# How do I write unit tests that verify a hook is being fired?

Tags: hooks, unit-testing, phpunit

I found [this example](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/Civi/Test/ExampleHookTest.php) but it doesn't look like it would generalise to all hooks.

The use case is for [API4](https://github.com/civicrm/api4/pull/47) - basically whenever any action is called I think we should be able to verify that particular hooks (and only those hooks) are called.

Comment: +1 on this, as I wanted to test that hook inputs correspond to the specs and did not find a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured this out. The specific hook engine for unit testing, very conveniently, comes with an injectable mock property.

After grabbing the hook engine with `$this->hookClass = \CRM_Utils_Hook::singleton()` you just need to inject a mock object that has a magic `__call()` method with somthing like:

`$this->hookClass->setMock($this);`

The hook engine will then call your `__call($name, $arguments)` method with every hook invocation.

You can see a fuller example [here](https://github.com/ErichBSchulz/api4/commit/6c9e2e0676969ac8cedfe23e036815092d2ca814) (please ignore the reporting stuff going on - I doubt that is best practice! Also the use of the unit test class as the mock is a bit lazy - its probably best to make a new class to provide the mock)